# Recreating Chrome's Faux Italics in SVG

Tags: css, firefox, svg, font-face, google-webfonts

I'm using some google web fonts for dynamically rendered svg logos. The fonts I'm using don't have italic versions and I'm actually pretty happy with the way Chrome fakes it when I put `font-style="italic"`. The only problem is that firefox doesn't seem to fake it at all. This fiddle shows it: http://jsfiddle.net/a6C32/3/

Is there a set way of recreating that Chrome functionality across all browsers?

Just to clarify what I'm seeing:
Chrome (36.0.1985.125 OSX):

[image: Chrome Faux Italics]

Firefox (31.0 OSX):

[image]

**UPDATE**: so after playing around with it some more, it turns out Firefox will do faux italics *unless* the text element also has a `stroke` defined on it: http://jsfiddle.net/a6C32/4/

Comment: Works for me on Firefox 31 on Windows 8

Comment: It's italicized? I'm in firefox 31.0 on OSX and see it straight.

Comment: Im on Firefox 30 on OSX and i see it italicized

Comment: Just upgraded to Firefox 31.0 on OSX 10.9.4 and its italic still for me

Comment: I had the font installed locally and improperly imported in fiddle, which would explain some of it. I just updated it here: http://jsfiddle.net/a6C32/3/

Comment: Ehhhh see update. It's just firefox not doing faux italics on text elements with strokes.

Comment: Report it as a bug in bugzilla. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core&component=SVG

Comment: @RobertLongson https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1048714 Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely a bug in Mozilla. My quick fix with SVG magic:-

`font-style="normal" transform="translate(10,0) skewX(-20)"`